# Trying to apply a function to a data frame returns 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

When I run the following script I get the following error message: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable.`

I basically have a dataframe called 'abc' and a dictionary 'abcquintile'.
my abcquintile acts as my base for segmenting my values in my dataframe.
My dictionary looks like this:

```
         a         b        c
0.2     100        10       20
0.4     250        20       50
0.6     350        40       80
0.8     600       120      200>


abcquintile = abc[['a', 'b', 'c']].quantile(q=[0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80])
abcquintile = abc.to_dict


# Arguments (x = value)
def ascore(x):
    if x <= abcquintile['a'][0.20]:
        return 5
    elif x <= abcquintile['a'][0.40]:
        return 4
    elif x <= abcquintile['a'][0.60]:
        return 3
    elif x <= abcquintile['a'][0.80]:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1


# Arguments (x = value, p = b or c)
def bcscore(x, p):
    if x <= abcquintile[p][0.20]:
        return 1
    elif x <= abcquintile[p][0.40]:
        return 2
    elif x <= abcquintile[p][0.60]:
        return 3
    elif x <= abcquintile[p][0.80]:
        return 4
    else:
        return 5


abc['a_quintile'] = abc['a'].apply(lambda x: ascore(x))
abc['b_quintile'] = abc['b'].apply(lambda x: bcscore(x, 'b'))
abc['c_quintile'] = abc['c'].apply(lambda x: bcscore(x, 'c'))
```

Comment: You didn't call `to_dict`. You forgot the parentheses.

Comment: wow... i can't believe this. thanks man how do i make this thread solved?